# How to use webdriver to randomly click on a button with precondication

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I'm trying to write a test script with flight booking tickets scenario like this: Randomly click a button which description contains keyword "tax not included",then results shows; Randomly click a button which not contains keyword, then price shows.

For instance: Go to ebay.com and search "iPhone",in the search result page,randomly click a url which label contains keyword "Buy It Now"...

Anybody got a clean solution to that? Thanks in advance.

I have no clue to handle this case...
here is my code:

```
    public void flightSchedule(){
    if (be.isTextPresent(locator.getValue("tax_text"), 1000)){  //if keywords displays
        ArrayList<WebElement> lists = (ArrayList<WebElement>) be.getBrowserCore().findElements(contains(text(),'tax not included'));

        Random random = new Random();
        int ra =  random.nextInt(lists.size());
        WebElement element = (WebElement) lists.get(ra);


    }
```

the page source code is：

```
<div id="itemBarXI151" class="avt_column avt_column_trans">
<div class="b_avt_lst">
<div class="avt_trans">
<div class="avt_column_1st">
<div class="avt_column_sp">
    <p>
        <span class="highlight">new york city</span>
        (tax not included)
    </p>
</div>
<div class="avt_column_2nd">
</div>
<div class="c6">
<div class="c7"> </div>
<div class="c8">
    <div class="a_booking">
        <a id="openwrapperbtnXI147" class="btn_book" title="booking tickets" onfocus="this.blur();" hidefocus="on" href="##" data-evtdataid="XI147">
            <span>
            <b>booking</b>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

my xpath is:"//div[@class='avt_column avt_column_trans'] [contains(text(),'booking')]",but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: :( I do not know how to start this case. using dyadic array?

Comment: That looks good enough. just ensure that "lists" contains only the inputs/buttons you need and then do an "element.Click()"

Comment: Still not work,I can not locate the button element...